How can I change a streaks of numbers according to the previous streak?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2],
    }
)

Expected output: Changing column a:
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8  -1
9  -1
10  2
11  2
12  2

The process is as follows:
a) Finding streaks of 1s and 2s
b) If a streak of 2 comes after a streak of 1, that streak of 2 changes to 1.
For example:
From rows 3 to 7 there is a streak of 2s. The streak before that is streak of 1s. So I want tot change rows 3 to 7 to 1 which is the expected output of this df.
These are my attemps:
# attempt 1
df['streak'] = df.a.ne(df.a.shift(1)).cumsum()
# attempt 2
df.loc[(df.a.eq(2)) & (df.a.shift(1).eq(1)), 'a'] = 1


what is the length of a streak? 1, 5?

@sammywemmy Whatever the length of streak of 2 is. It is not a fixed number. All of them changes to 1

Please, check if my solution for your problem works.

@deviep11 Thanks a lot. I want a vectorized solution. When a loop is used in Pandas DataFrame, something should be double checked :)

You can use shift and ffill to access the previous group, then boolean indexing:
# previous value
s = df['a'].shift()
# check if previous group is 1
m1 = s.where(df['a'].ne(s)).ffill().eq(1)
# is value 2?
m2 = df['a'].eq(2)

df.loc[m1&m2, 'a'] = 1

Output:
    a
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8  -1
9  -1
10  2
11  2
12  2

Intermediates:
    a    s  where  ffill     m1     m2
0   1  NaN    NaN    NaN  False  False
1   1  1.0    NaN    NaN  False  False
2   1  1.0    NaN    NaN  False  False
3   2  1.0    1.0    1.0   True   True
4   2  2.0    NaN    1.0   True   True
5   2  2.0    NaN    1.0   True   True
6   2  2.0    NaN    1.0   True   True
7   2  2.0    NaN    1.0   True   True
8  -1  2.0    2.0    2.0  False  False
9  -1 -1.0    NaN    2.0  False  False
10  2 -1.0   -1.0   -1.0  False   True
11  2  2.0    NaN   -1.0  False   True
12  2  2.0    NaN   -1.0  False   True

